# Can't build .exe using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I have 2 files, One is Main.py other one is Autoe.ui, I want both as a single .exe
I tried

```
pyinstaller -w --add-data="Autoe.ui;." Main.py
```

This works just fine, but it creates lot of other files as well, I wanted just a single exe, So I tried this

```
pyinstaller.exe -w --onefile --add-data="Autoe.ui;." Main.py
```

This creates a single .exe but it won't run, I get a pop-up saying "Failed to execute script Main"

Comment: Did you try to build them separately?

Comment: Yes, the Autoe.ui using PyQt Designer and then integrated through python script, both are in the same folder

Comment: you don't need to include this file as an extra one if you've already integrated it through python. PyInstaller will include it automatically.

Comment: to be 100% sure that the `ui` is included, you can use `pyuic5` command to convert it from `.ui` to `.py` file.

Comment: @stilManiac Integrate as in I loaded the ui like this, `uic.loadUi("Autoe.ui", self) `
And now I tried to build the .exe using just the python file, same error. This time it didn't work with `pyinstaller -w  Main.py` as well. So I guess I do need to add the .ui file

Comment: Any errors during building process?

Comment: @stilManiac You mean convert it before making it to a executable file? Then I'll have to change my whole python script, If you mean after making it to a executable file, there's just one .exe file

Comment: @stilManiac Nope just fine, as I said it works fine when I do this `pyinstaller -w --add-data="Autoe.ui;." Main.py` but not when I do this `pyinstaller.exe -w --onefile --add-data="Autoe.ui;." Main.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Kivy app. In my case it was a kv file, not a ui. Maybe what I did will help you.
In the folder with the * .py file I ran the command:

`pyinstaller --onefile -y --clean --windowed --icon=someicon.ico main.py`

The main.spec file appeared in the folder. I have edited it.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(["main.py"],
             pathex=["C:\\Users\\underground\\Desktop\\gdc"], #<<<<<<<path to folder of your app
             binaries=[]
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
             
a.datas += [('gdc.kv', 'C:\\Users\\underground\\Desktop\\gdc\\gdc.kv', 'DATA')]  #<<<< I added kv file to a.datas
excluded_binaries = ['VCRUNTIME140.dll']                        #<<<< I disabled this library because my app won't start on win10
a.binaries = TOC([x for x in a.binaries if x[0] not in excluded_binaries])

exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('C:\\Users\\underground\\Desktop\\gdc\\Data','Data'), 
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='ikona.ico')
```

When I edited the spec file, I ran pyintaller again but gave the spec file instead of the * .py file.

`pyinstaller main.spec`

...that's all.
You can also try the GUI version - auto-py-to-exe instead of pyinstaller.

Comment: Both methods didn't work, I'll just pack it as a folder for now